# Как правильно настроить вывод ошибок в Yii2 api?

Tags: yii2

Пишу апи сайта на отдельном домене api.site.ru

Использую basic шаблон, контроллеры и модели апи вынес в папку `modules/v1/`

Например, при запросе на несуществующую страницу api.site.ru/asdqwe, сервер выдаёт 
404 ошибку, но вместе с html кодом, даже через консоль.

Как переопределить и выводить ошибки без шаблона и html кода?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Видимо Вам надо настроить response. Если везде, то через конфиг, если в конкретном экшене, то можно так:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
Yii::$app->response->setStatusCode(404,'Вы запросили не существующую хрень'));
return false;
```

А по поводу глобально в конфиге - это описано в доках в разделе RESTful Web Service:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html